# How to add user to own database during registration in a 'transactional' way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use AWS Cognito for my app.

I can register the users successfully to AWS Cognito, but I want to be able to also store them in my database (with my own API), too, as part of the sign-up process.

I saw that I could use a trigger function like Post confirmation, but as far as I understand, if saving the user to my database fails, then the user will still be created in the Cognito user pool.

I want to treat the sign-up process in a transactional way, so that if saving the user in my database fails, then the entire process fails.

So, it would look something like this:

```
  Aws Cognito Sign Up -> Send_to_database_trigger ----fails----> user is not created 
                                                  \---success--> user is created
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html).

It gets the username and all the user attributes in the event and if it fails the user won't be signed up in Cognito.

In your case, you will save your user to your database in this trigger (after other possible validations) and will fail if saving to your database has failed. This way you can be sure that if a user exists in Cognito it also exists in your database.

If you need to save the `sub` then you can implement both Pre Sign-up and Post Confirmation and update your database record with the `sub` in the Post Confirmation trigger.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is used for validation so that if it doesn't meet some requirements, then the user won't be signed up.

Comment: You can write you own logic in there, so in your case your "custom validation" is that writing to your database has succeeded. If you need to add more validation you can do it in there also before writing to your database.

Comment: Yes, but in this case there is the inverse problem: what if the trigger somehow fails? Then, it will leave unwanted user information in the database.

Comment: If you are "returning" immediately after saving to your database there is no reason why Cognito will fail. Also, chances are that Cognito will always have a better availability and retry logic than your database so doing it in this order should be better.

Comment: You can also have a scheduled Lambda function to clean your database in the rare event that Cognito fails after the trigger.

Comment: There is another problem that I didn't mention. You don't have access to the sub property in Pre sign-up...

Comment: In this case you need to implement both pre sign-up and post confirmation and update your database record in post confirmation. In case of error, it will be easy to clean your database by checking which records don't have a `sub` (periodic check).

Comment: Note: The Pre sign-up trigger is invoked whenever a call to signup is made even when the user already exists in cognito, password does not match the policy, attributes did not conform to the schema, etc..  that being said I don't think using this trigger would solve this problem because we still have to deal with the fact that a user can exist in the database without actually making it to cognito.

Comment: do I have the user ID available on PreSignup?

Comment: No, it's not available.